# Bring container view to front

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have stacked a bunch of container views on top of one another and am hiding / unhiding based on user clicks elsewhere on the screen like below:

```
[self.childViewControllers[13] view].hidden = NO;
```

The hiding/unhiding is working fine BUT only one of them lets the controls on it be used.....it is the top one.

How do I reorder when hiding/unhiding for user clicks please?

I have now tried the following based on the answers yesterday:

```
UIView *x = self.childViewControllers[12];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:x];
```

but it gives the error

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have also tried:

```
UIView *x = self.childViewControllers[12];
        x.layer.zPosition = 100;
```

which gives the same error message
thanks lots

Comment: Show the code you using to try to bring one of the child view controller's views to the front.

Comment: In the first attempt of your updated question, change `x` to be a `UIViewController`. Then call `bringSubviewToFront:` with `x.view`.

Comment: Hi Maddy. Your changes work.....no errors and correct container at front. However the controls still don't react to user input (except on the one originally drawn on the top of the stack in the storyboard). I'm going to have to give up and use them as popovers instead which isn't as god for the user :o(

Comment: Check the answer by befstrat, he is correct, you should be using the `superview` of the viewController's `view` instead of the `view` directly.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
It seems that when using Container Views the actual content view controller view is placed inside a transparent container view. So if you want to really hide a Container View displaying View v, you should use

```
v.superview.hidden = YES
```

instead of

```
v.hidden = YES
```

Comment: man you are awesome, I've spent a lot of time debugging the hierarchy of the view and didn't catch this, thanks its worked like charm!

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:desiredView]
```

This will resolve your problem in a better way.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion but it gives the following error:unrecognized selector sent to instance. I have added the code I used to my original question. thanks

Comment: UIView *x = self.childViewControllers[12];
instead of this you soould use 

UIView *x = self.childViewControllers[12].view;


[self.view bringSubviewToFront:x];

and your problem will be resolved

Comment: property view not found on object of type id.

Comment: then how can you use [self.childViewControllers[13] view].hidden = NO; if you are able to use this then you should use  UIView *x = self.childViewControllers[12].view;

Comment: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:desiredView] will not work. You need to bring to front the superview's view. eg: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:desiredView.superview]

Answer (score 0):

You can bring(reorder) any subview to front using the following :-

```
viewToBeShown.hidden=FALSE;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewToBeShown];
```

This method will bring the viewToBeShown on to the top of every subview in self.view

Hope it will help you .

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion but it gives the following error:unrecognized selector sent to instance. I have added the code I used to my original question. thanks

Comment: Have allocated the view you wanted to bring in front . the error which you are getting because you are trying to access any deallocated instance not because of the above code . Verify it and let me know if it helps you . :)

Comment: yes, they are all allocated automatically on viewdidload since I added them on the storyboard. They hide & unhide fine but whichever I list last in storyboard document outline is the only one that accepts user interaction.

Comment: have you also added the Outlet of the subviews to your viewController class ?

Comment: No. I'll have a look at that next (thx). However the last added one does work which I also haven't done that for either. Will ge back to this this evening. thx again

Comment: sorry wasn't this, dragging onto the storyboard seems to link it all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an outlet from the storyboard to the `container view`, and hide it!

In swift:

```
func setViewEnabled(view:UIView, enabled:Bool)
{
    view.hidden = !enabled
    view.userInteractionEnabled = enabled
}
```